# How to keep polling a bound service?

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

I looked up on the internet, but couldn't find an example covering my scenario. What I am trying to do is:

> 1) To start and bind to a service as soon as my activity starts ***(done)***
>
> 2) The service then binds itself to another service looking for a user
>   input from a connected device, and saves a string a string to a variable **(done)**
>
> 3) I would like to send back this string to the activity, so I can check what it
>   is and based on it to make a network call.

Now number 3) is my challenge. I managed to do it with a Timer that runs for one second and then checks the value written in the service, but somehow this doesn't seem to be the right way and I think that there might be a more mature solution. However, I can't seem to figure it out.

I've taken the code from the documentation and only added the timer. It is just one service in this example that just generates a random number (this will normally be replaced by my second service).
This is the code for the service:

```
public class LocalService extends Service {

    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    private final Random mGenerator = new Random();

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        LocalService getService() {
            return LocalService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public int getRandomNumber() {
        return mGenerator.nextInt(100);
    }
}
```

And this is the code in my activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LocalService mService;
    boolean mBound = false;
    Timer timer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        timer = new Timer();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocalService.class);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        timer.schedule(new MyTimerTask(new Handler(), this), 1000, 1000); // run on every second
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mBound) {
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mBound = false;
        }

        timer.cancel();
        timer.purge();
    }

    private class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
        Handler handler;
        MainActivity ref;

        public MyTimerTask(Handler handler, MainActivity ref) {
            super();
            this.handler = handler;
            this.ref = ref;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (mBound) {
                        int num = ref.mService.getRandomNumber();
                        // just as an example, raise a toast to see if it works
                        // but otherwise the value will be handled
                        Toast.makeText(ref, "number: " + num, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                       IBinder service) {
            LocalService.LocalBinder binder = (LocalService.LocalBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };
}
```

My question is: is this a good approach (it works) or is it bad and what's the alternative?

Comment: you have a bound service so dont use broadcast receivers:  you have a bound connection after all,  just pass an interface object to your service and let the service call it somewhere

Comment: @pskink I am not sure what you mean by letting the service call the interface object?

Comment: in your `LocalService` create a method `register(ISomeInterface)` and when your activity binds to your service (inside `onServiceConnected`) call `mService.register(MainActivity.this)`, of course `MainActivity` has to implement `ISomeInterface`, that way if you call `register` your service can store `ISomeInterface` in a private field and call some of its method later on, if there are several clients your service can use a `List` of them or `android.os.RemoteCallbackList` class which is designed for such case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `LocalBroadcastManager` to send broadcasts from your `Service` to your `Activity`. For example, in your `Service` declare:

```
public static final String BROADCAST_INTENT = "broadcast_intent";
public static final String BROADCAST_VALUE = "broadcast_value";

private LocalBroadcastManager broadcastManager;

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    broadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
}
```

Now whenever you want to send a `String` to your `Activity` you can do so like this:

```
private void sendBroadcast(String value) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_INTENT);
    intent.putExtra(BROADCAST_VALUE, value);
    broadcastManager.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

In your `Activity` declare a `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        handleIntent(intent);
    }
};
```

Register the receiver when you bind to your `Service`:

```
IntentFilter broadcastIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
broadcastIntentFilter.addAction(StreamService.BROADCAST_INTENT);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver((broadcastReceiver), broadcastIntentFilter);
```

And unregister where you unbind from your `Service`:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
```

Now when your service sends the broadcast you can handle it in your `Activity`:

```
private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

    if (intent.getAction().equals(StreamService.BROADCAST_INTENT)) {
        String value = intent.getStringExtra(StreamService.BROADCAST_VALUE, "default");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a very nice example! Just one question: should the registering and un-registering of the receiver be done in `onServiceConnected` and `onServiceDisconnected` or is it fine do it in `onStart` and `onStop` ?

Comment: `onStop()` and `onStart()` is fine!

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to send back this string to the activity, so I can check what it is and based on it to make a network call.

Use `LocalBroadcastManager`, greenrobot's EventBus, Square's Otto, or some other in-process event bus implementation. Raise an event when you have changed data. Have the activity register with the bus to find out about the event. Have the activity use the changed data when the change occurs.

> is this a good approach

No.